# PL/SQL: How to delete records in a specific manner, for example if records of specific type X exist, delete all but one record

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm trying to create a  PL/SQL procedure where by I delete records that are grouped and selected by cursor but I only want one record remaining.  I want to delete first by Xcomment, if there are multiple entries with id_number, activity_code, start_dt, activity_participation_code exist, then delete all but ONE entry with blank/null xcomment. If there are multiple entries with blank xcomment, then delete all but one with blank table_nmb.  If multiple entries with blank table_nmb then delete highest sequence until only one is left.  Essentially, I only want one record per all these fields.  I'm having trouble thinking of how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
Create Or Replace Function Y_Cleanup_Cursor
  Return Sys_Refcursor
As
  My_Cursor Sys_Refcursor;
Begin
  Open My_Cursor For 
    Select Q.Id_Number, Q.Activity_Code, Q.Start_Dt, Q.Activity_Participation_Code, Q.Rec_Count, A.Xcomment, A.Table_Nmb, A.Xsequence
     From (Select Id_Number, Activity_Code, Start_Dt, Activity_Participation_Code, Count(0) As Rec_Count
        From Activity A
        Group By Id_Number, Activity_Code, Start_Dt, Activity_Participation_Code
        Having Count(0) > 1) Q, 
        Activity A
        Where 
            Q.Id_Number = A.Id_Number And 
            Q.Activity_Code = A.Activity_Code And 
            Q.Start_Dt = A.Start_Dt And  
            Q.Activity_Participation_Code = A.Activity_Participation_Code;
  Return My_Cursor;
End Y_Cleanup_Cursor;


Create Or Replace Procedure Help_Me_Please(Code In Varchar2)
Is
--  Declare Variables
--  I Stands For Internal Variable

    L_Cursor                        Sys_Refcursor;

    I_Id_Number                     Varchar2(10 Byte);
    I_Xsequence                     Number  (6); 
    I_Activity_Code                 Varchar2(05 Byte); 
    I_Start_Dt                      Varchar2(08 Byte); 
    I_Activity_Participation_Code   Varchar2(02 Byte); 
    I_Table_Nmb                     Varchar2(15 Byte); 
    I_Xcomment                      Varchar2(255 Byte);
    I_Rec_Count                     Number  (6);

    L_Counter                       Integer;

Begin

    L_Cursor := Y_Cleanup_Cursor;

    Loop
      Fetch L_Cursor Into 
        I_Id_Number, I_Activity_Code, I_Start_Dt, I_Activity_Participation_Code, I_Rec_Count, I_Xcomment, I_Table_Nmb, I_Xsequence;

        Select Count (Id_Number)
        Into L_Counter
        From Activity Where
                                  Id_Number = I_Id_Number 
            And               Activity_Code = I_Activity_Code
            And                    Start_Dt = I_Start_Dt 
            And Activity_Participation_Code = I_Activity_Participation_Code
            And Trim(Xcomment) Is Null;

     If L_Counter <> I_Rec_Count Then
        Begin
            Delete From Activity
            Where 
                                  Id_Number = I_Id_Number 
            And               Activity_Code = I_Activity_Code
            And                    Start_Dt = I_Start_Dt 
            And Activity_Participation_Code = I_Activity_Participation_Code
            And Trim(Xcomment) Is Null;
        end;
     End If;
        Exit When L_Cursor%Notfound;
    End Loop;

    Close L_Cursor;  
End Help_Me_Please;
```

Comment: And the problem is..?

Comment: I need ideas on how to create this logic because I can't think of any way of doing it myself.  I don't need to see code, I just need to see a skeleton structure of how to implement the logic behind this.

Comment: Does the ACTIVITY table have a primary key?

Comment: Yes it does, primary keys for activity table are id_number and xsequence

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you want to delete all rows except 1 where there are repeating columns

first make sure to backup your table:

```
create table [backup_table] as select * from [table];
```

Try This:

```
DELETE FROM backup_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM backup_table
GROUP BY [col1], [col2]);
```

Col1 and col2, etc are the columns that should be identical

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot and see how it goes but i will try using primary keys for ACTIVITY, id_number an xsequence,  instead of rowid.

Comment: rowid is a hidden row on every table, if you have an auto increment field then you could use that aswell but rowid will always work with oracle